# WP_Query pagination on a custom endpoint in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I have created a class that creates a `custom endpoint` for WooCommerce My Account and on this endpoint I am trying to add the lists of products with pagination using `WP_Query`.

Here is the code:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;            
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        $query = new \WP_Query( $args );
        while( $query->have_posts() ):
            $query->the_post();
            echo get_the_title().'<br>';
        endwhile;

        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
            'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
            'show_all'     => false,
            'type'         => 'plain',
            'end_size'     => 2,
            'mid_size'     => 1,
            'prev_next'    => true,
            'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'add_args'     => false,
            'add_fragment' => '',
        ) );
```

The pagination links appear just fine and the correct number of page links.

The problem is that the get_query_var('paged') is always 0.

I checked using `var_dump get_query_var('paged')`. I am guessing that it has something to do with the fact that I am creating the WP_Query instance on an endpoint.

Anyone have any ideas if `WP_Query` with pagination can work on a custom endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

After getting some good sleep, I came back to this issue this morning and with fresh eyes and I could see what was causing the issue.

As this was a custom endpoint the '`paged`' variable was being added to the custom endpoint query variable, in this case called 'listings'.

If I `var_dump` the `listings` query variable I get `page/2` etc.  So I wrote

```
if( empty( get_query_var('listings') ) ):
    $paged = 1;
else:
    $paged_array = explode('/',get_query_var('listings'));
    $paged = $paged_array[1];
endif;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged
);
```

This allowed me to get a paged variable and now the pagination works.

Seems like a bit of a hack, but not sure how else to get a paged variable from an endpoint

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to add pagination to an endpoint with wp_query. Can you please explain what the `listings` query variable is? My question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71601846/1354580

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I could fix this today after a week of struggle.

**1. Add Custom Endpoint in Child Theme's functions.php:**
Register your custom endpoint in the functions.php file of your child theme.

```
function register_custom_endpoints()      
{add_rewrite_endpoint('listings', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES);               
} 
add_action('init', 'register_custom_endpoints');
```

**2. Set Up Pagination in Template File:**

```
$paged = get_query_var('listings') ? get_query_var('listings') : 1; $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'tag__in' => array($first_tag), 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID), 'orderby' => 'publish_date','posts_per_page' => 12, 'paged' => $paged, ); $query = new WP_Query($args);$product_slug = get_post_field('post_name', get_queried_object_id()); $pagination_args = array( 'total' => $query->max_num_pages,'current' => $paged, 'format' => '/%#%', 'base' => home_url('/product/' . $product_slug . '/listings/%#%/'), ); echo '<div class="pagination">' . paginate_links($pagination_args) . '</div>'; wp_reset_postdata();
```

**3. Flush Rewrite Rules**

Hope this helps fixing the pagination in custom end point pages.

Answer (score 0):

To get a dynamic slug from the single custom post type in the pagination, I used the following code: (ex: domain.com/product/listings/1)

```
// Get the current post type
$current_post_type = get_post_type(get_queried_object_id());

// Get the post type object and extract the singular name
$post_type_object = get_post_type_object($current_post_type);
$singular_slug = isset($post_type_object->rewrite['slug']) ? $post_type_object->rewrite['slug'] : $current_post_type;

// Get the current post slug
$current_post_slug = get_post_field('post_name', get_queried_object_id());

// Set up the pagination arguments
$pagination_args = array(
  'total'     => $query->max_num_pages,
  'current'   => $paged,
  'format'    => 'listings/%#%/',
  'base'      => home_url('/' . $singular_slug . '/' . $current_post_slug . '/listings/%#%/'),
);
```